# Mark BWA-SW split alignments in output for long reads

Tags: sequence-alignment, bwa, sam, long-reads

Is there a way to remove split alignments of single-end long reads from BWA-SW output? BWA-MEM has an option to include or flag split alignments in the result, but it seems BWA-SW method include them in the result unless the split occur in paired-end reads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [BWA manual](http://bio-bwa.sourceforge.net/bwa.shtml), it is advised to use BWA-MEM in your longs read case (unless you have a good reason not to):

> BWA-MEM and BWA-SW share similar features such as long-read support and split alignment, but BWA-MEM, which is the latest, is generally recommended for high-quality queries as it is faster and more accurate.

I guess that BWA-SW returns several lines per transcript (based on local alignments). In that case, the [issue has already been reported](https://sourceforge.net/p/bio-bwa/mailman/message/31199486/). The user asks:

> How can I differentiate between a read that has multiple hits in the reference and a read that has a split alignment?

The author replies:

> In principle, it is hard to tell. Bwa-mem makes an arbitrary choice.
>   Mappings flagged with 0x100 are multiple hits. Mappings flagged with
>   0x800 are from a chimeric alignment.

So you could actually filter by [flag](https://broadinstitute.github.io/picard/explain-flags.html). But I am afraid the output could include something you do not necessarily want to (since there is no specific flag for the split reads).

Maybe a better solution: you could switch to some mapper that will report the proper split in the hit of the read map, such as [minimap2](https://github.com/lh3/minimap2) from the same author. It is suitable for long reads and comes with a `splice -x` feature.

Then, the laziest solution I see here would be to remove the split alignments exploiting the [sam format](https://samtools.github.io/hts-specs/SAMv1.pdf) and in particular the CIGAR string. Meaning, to remove the sam fields containing a `N` in their CIGAR (aka, skipped region from the reference). Something like this would work:

```
cat alignment.sam | awk '$6 !~ /N/ {print $0}'
```

Hope this can be somewhat helpful.